# Link failure with versioned symbols (memcpy & secure_getenv)

Tags: c, linux, ld, glibc

I am seeing undefined symbols when trying to link shared libraries with a program on Redhat Linux.
We are running Linux kernel 3.10.0, gcc 4.8.2 with libc-2.17.so, and libblkid 2.23.2

When I build the application I am writing I get two undefined symbols from libblkid:  `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14` and `secure_getenv@GLIBC_2.17`. (A very similar build works on other machines, ostensibly using the same versions of everything).

Note, for `secure_getenv` libblkid wants the same version as the libc library itself.

Looking at the symbols defined in libc-2.17.so I find `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14`, `memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5`, `secure_getenv`, and `secure_getenv@GLIBC_2.2.5`. According to my understanding the double `@` in the first `memcpy` version is simply supposed to mark it as the default version. And, for some reason even in this libc with versioned symbols the first `secure_getenv` appears to be unversioned.

So, why does a requirement for `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14` not match the defaulted `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14`?

And logically I would expect the base version of `secure_getenv` in libc-2.17 to match a requirement for version 2.17.

So, what is going on here? What is making it fail on my development machine and not others? How do I fix this? (As the make works on other machines this appears to be something specific to my build environment, but what?)

Comment: Show your link command. Are there any binaries you have not compiled yourself? Do you have anything in /usr/local/lib\*?

Comment: Here it is for real:
@n.m The basic link line is cc -o myapp app_main.o file1.o file2.o file3.o -g --verbose -DDEBUG -fPIC -L/usr/lib/gcc -lgcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/lib64/ -lm -lpthread -Llib64 -Llib -lcommon -lcrypto -lssl -ldl -lblkid -lnv_env -lnv_io.

liblzo2 is in /usr/local/lib
Apparently libcommon, libcrypto and libssl are project level .a files.

P.S. forgot to mention this is 64 bit Linux, and most libraries are in /usr/lib64.

Comment: Anything that is not yours in `/usr/local/lib*`? Try to rearrange your libraries in dependency order .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause.  You don't need things like -lggc or -L/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/lib64/, these are automatic by gcc.

Comment: Weird. Removing the excess -L options and -lgcc fixed it.  Those were being added by a line in the makefile that checks if gcc is being used and adds those if it is _not_ being used. And since for some reason the compiler is being called as 'cc' instead of 'gcc' it invoked that branch.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have `compat-glibc` installed, as indicated by the `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/lib64` argument.  `compat-glibc` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 provides glibc 2.12 only, so it cannot be used to link against system libraries.